# How to get Facebook AppID for an existing comments App?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I am already using a Facebook comments app but need to integrate an AppID. I cannot find anywhere how to get one of these without creating a new app. I want to get the ID of the existing comments app I am using. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get an app id by creating an app. You can then use the newly created app's app id. How does this not make sense? :)

The fact that you implemented the comments plugin doesn't mean you created an app (or that you already have an app id). You won't lose your comments as they are tied to the URL. Adding an app id to the plugin allows you to moderate the comments, but you won't lose them.

Comment: So, all I do now is add my new AppID to the Facebook comments in the page?

Comment: Yup :) That should allow you to moderate comments.